# Missing functions vload and vstore: OpenCL on Android

Tags: android, arm, opencl, gpu

I've been looking for a solution to this for days, but I'm at a loss.

I'm running openCL kernels on a Galaxy S6 and it all seems to be working fine except for when I try to use these functions in my kernel code: vload16() and vstore16().

When I run the kernel on my Mac's CPU using the Mali SDK, everything runs fine. I compared the header files in the Mali SDK to those in my android project and the only difference seems to be that the Mali SDK on my laptop has a header file named cl_d3d10.h whereas the Android project doesn't.

Does anybody have any suggestions to figure out how to get vload and vstore to work on Android? It's fine loading vectors manually when they have 4 components, but loading a uchar16 vector component by component is clearly inefficient.

Comment: When you try and use  vload16()  what is the error?  Is it   a compile error, undefined external reference or what?   Does vload8() work? You may want to check the clGetDeviceInfo for each device to see the device's preferred vector width. It may be that vload16() isn't support as it exceeds the preferred vector width.

Comment: Are your addresses aligned with the width of the vector you are using? Because vload/vstore require that.

Comment: Dithermaster: No, they don't, they just require a pointer to be aligned to the data type's alignment, not the vector's. [link](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/vloadn.html) So `vload`'ing `float16` data requires a pointer that is aligned to '32 bits' (`==alignof(float)`). Although I have no idea how the `const float*` parameter `vload16` would be not aligned to 32 bits..

Comment: vload and vstore are kernel functions. Why do you try to find support from header files? Those functions are standard functions from the spec. If that is not supported, that means the compiler in the device driver has a bug or something.